# Best way to implement matrix padding

Tags: matlab, matrix, padding

I'm trying to pad a matrix filled with zeros at the borders with the values at the pixel which is closest to the border, for example:

```
A = rand(5);
Z = zeros(9);
Z(3:7, 3:7) = A;
```

[image]

Now I'd like to complete the matrix borders in the following way:

[image]

I'm looking for a nice solution without any for-loops

EDIT:

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're trying to do. Can you elaborate?

Comment: To add to Phonon's comment, how does your matrix relate to the image? Why are there two rows/columns of zeros?

Comment: Hmmm...I'd like to replicate the values in the inner 5x5 matrix to the 2 border rows and columns in a way which is described by the picture in the bottom. The highlighted box corresponds to this 5x5 matrix. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% Create a random image
I = round(rand(8)*70);

% Number of pixels to pad on each side
padSize = 3;

% Create a resulting image matric
sizeY = size(I,1);
sizeX = size(I,2);

J = zeros( sizeY + padSize*2, sizeX + padSize*2 );

% Fill in the original
J( (padSize+1):(padSize+sizeY) , (padSize+1):(padSize+sizeX) ) = I;

% Fill in areas above, below and to the sides or original
%top
J( 1:padSize, (padSize+1):(padSize+sizeX) ) = repmat(I(1,:),padSize,1);
%bottom
J( (padSize+sizeX+1):end, (padSize+1):(padSize+sizeX) ) = repmat(I(end,:),padSize,1);
%left
J( (padSize+1):(padSize+sizeY), 1:padSize ) = repmat(I(:,1),1,padSize);
%right
J( (padSize+1):(padSize+sizeY), (padSize+sizeY+1):end ) = repmat(I(:,end),1,padSize);

% Fill in the corners
J(1:padSize, 1:padSize)                         = I(1,1);
J((padSize+sizeY+1):end, 1:padSize)             = I(end,1);
J(1:padSize, (padSize+sizeX+1):end)             = I(1,end);
J((padSize+sizeY+1):end, (padSize+sizeX+1):end) = I(end,end);
```

Answer (score 5):

You want [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) with the `'replicate'` option. For example to replicate 2x2 borders on all sides,

```
>> A = [1 2; 3 4];
>> B = padarray(A,[2 2],'replicate','both')
B =
     1     1     1     2     2     2
     1     1     1     2     2     2
     1     1     1     2     2     2
     3     3     3     4     4     4
     3     3     3     4     4     4
     3     3     3     4     4     4
```

Comment: I've looked at `padarray` but I couldn't find out how to replicate it properly. So far only my zeros get replicated if I use `padarray(Z, [2 2], 'replicate')`

Comment: @Schnigges - Use `padarray` on the matrix without the zeros. No need to embed the matrix in zeros first.  If you only have the matrix with zeros already there, run it like `padarray(Z(3:7, 3:7), [2 2], 'replicate')`

Comment: Thanks, but as a matter of fact I have to use the image which already contains the zeros at the border.

Comment: @Schnigges - OK, so you can use `padarray(Z(3:7, 3:7), [2 2], 'replicate')`.